# AoT errors in production mode

Tags: angular, typescript, aot

So in my project I have components and services and I have included services where I need them. To do so I declared all the services as private in the constructor. For example:

```
constructor(private myService: MyService) {}
```

But in the html template I have used the service like `([ngModel])="myService.name"`. And here is the issue, when I tried to build in production mode I had a lot of AoT errors saying that I was using a private property which was only accessible within the class for each service I used in an html template. So I was wondering if it's a good practice to declare all the services as public to avoid the AoT errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either

- Add a public accessor to the property on the component that calls through to the service.

  ```
  get name():string {return this.myService.name;}
  ```
- Change `private` to `public` in the constructor

  ```
  constructor(public myService: MyService) {}
  ```

As far as which of these 2 is "correct" is a matter of opinion.

Comment: I'd argue the first option is better due to encapsulation. By keeping the service private and exposing the name property, it only exposes what *needs* to be exposed, and no more

Comment: @user184994 - Although option 1 would also be my preference it is still technically an opinion so I left it out of my answer.

Comment: however the first option wouldn't add a lot of "unnecessary" code?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to declare instance variables (e. g. your service) as public if you want to use them in a template.
Alternatively, declare a public method in your class so you don't have to use your service directly:

```
constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

getUsers(): User[] {
  return this.userService.getUsers();
}
```

Also, I'd recommend that you use AOT during development so that you get notified about those errors immediately. It should not take much longer anymore. `ng serve --aot`